# How to build a dynamic list view with 3 items in row in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to dynamically build a list view. I require to display only 3 list items in each row . But I'm getting the below error:

"A RenderFlex overflowed by 807 pixels on the bottom. The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical. The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex."

Also tried by implementing Expanded, Flex but could not.

Here is the code I was trying

```
    class ItemsList extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      State createState() => _ItemsListState();
     }

class _ItemsListState extends State<ItemsList> {

  String totalprice, itemCount, quantity;
  var itemcount = 0;

  // final List<Map<String, dynamic>> items;

  final List items = [
    {
      'title' : 'Appam',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Appam.png',
      'itemprice' : 50,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Bonda',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Bonda.png',
      'itemprice' : 25,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Dosa',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Dosa.png',
      'itemprice' : 40,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Idly',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Idly.png',
      'itemprice' : 30,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Onion Dosa',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Onion_Dosa.png',
      'itemprice' : 50,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
     {
      'title' : 'Parotta',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Parotta.png',
      'itemprice' : 50,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Puri',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Puri.png',
      'itemprice' : 40,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Upma',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/Upma.png',
      'itemprice' : 30,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Uttapam',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/uttapam.png',
      'itemprice' : 40,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
    {
      'title' : 'Vada',
      'imageUrl' : 'images/vada.png',
      'itemprice' : 30,
      'itemcount' : 0,
    },
  ];

  Widget _buildItemsList() {
    Widget itemCards;
    List items = this.items;
    if (items.length > 0) {
      itemCards =  GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        children: List.generate(items.length, (index){
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Card(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Container(
                  // width: 100.0,
                  // height: 110.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image(
                        image: AssetImage(items[index]['imageUrl']),
                        height: 80.0,
                        width: 80.0,
                      ),
                      Text(items[index]['title'])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
            ),
            onTap: _updateCart,
          );
        }),
      );
    } 
    else {
      itemCards = Container(
        child: Text('No items'),
      );
    }
    return itemCards;
  }

  Widget _buildOrderListBar(){
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(37, 134, 16, 1.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(itemcount>0?itemcount.toString(): '', 
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Checkout', 
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            onPressed: (){
              var route = MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => OrderDetails()
              );
              Navigator.push(context, route);
            },
          ),
          Text('Rs. $totalprice', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchItem() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Search for Item',
          icon: Icon(Icons.search)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

  }

  _updateCart(){
    setState(() {
      itemcount = ++itemcount;
      totalprice = (30 * itemcount).toString();
      print(totalprice);
      print(itemcount);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerItems(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ordering'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildOrderListBar(),
            _buildSearchItem(),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
              child: _buildItemsList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigatorItems(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
        onPressed: (){},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dU3V.png)

Comment: paste more code where is _buildItemsList() called. plus you need to return itemCards also in end.

Comment: Edited the question. I do have only two fields to display in the card.

Comment: your are using itemExtent: 3.0, what if you increase its size to itemExtent: 110.0 ?

Comment: No change of issue even if the itemExtent value changed

Comment: what is parent widget of _buildItemsList() ?

Comment: if possible attached the screenshot of the screen also where overflow is occurring

Comment: @anmol.majhail  attached the screenshot. This is happening when the itemExtent attribute is removed. If itemExtend attribute is added, even  the cards are not displayed

Comment: you have to paste more code as error is of parent widget not the above given code.

Comment: make the widget that is having _buildItemsList() scroll-able

Comment: Pasted complete page code

Comment: added the answer - wrap your buildItemsList() in Expanded Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Scaffold Body:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildOrderListBar(),
          _buildSearchItem(),
          Expanded(child: _buildItemsList()),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the support